# How to use crontab and mutt to execute a command and mail its output?

Tags: cron, email, ifconfig

Executing the command

```
echo "ifconfig" | bash | mutt -s "My IP" -- send@mail.com
```

at shell works. Output of `ifconfig` is included within mail.

However, adding the line

```
@reboot echo "ifconfig" | bash | mutt -s "My IP" -- send@mail.com
```

with `crontab -e`

only sends an e-mail with subject at system startup. Mail content is empty.

Comment: cron is probably started before network, you may whish to have a look at anacron, which could wait after boot.

Comment: @Archemar adding `sleep 60` after `@reboot` didn't work either.

Comment: @Archemar Here is what I did: `@reboot sleep 60 && /home/server/Desktop/send_ip.sh`. The contents of the script are: `ifconfig >> /home/server/Desktop/ip.txt && cat /home/server/Desktop/ip.txt | mutt -s "My IP" -- send@mail.com
`

Comment: @Archemar Could you mark the post as solved?

Comment: I cannot, but you might answer your own question, wait a bit and accept.